# WordPress date_query on custom field

Tags: wordpress

I have some Custom Post Types with a custom field (event_date) which holds a date. The current format for that date is F j, Y but I can change that format if needed. What I want to do is query the posts by year like:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'year'  => $year
    )
);
```

But I am using a custom field (event_date) how could I query this custom field in the same way?

my current query just gets all the posts:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use meta_query with wp_query. You can fire queries using that argument.

Cheers